# How do I start database container for testing in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: testing, azure-devops, containers, azure-pipelines

As a part of my pipeline, I'd like to test my golang application in a step of my pipeline but it depends on a database. I have a docker-compose file with the database container and a container that applies the migrations to the database. At this point, I'd like to run the go tests.

How can I best achieve this with Azure Pipelines?